# give a prefab clones a script from another prefab in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have the following :

TurretBallmanager :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TurretBallManager : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
public GameObject BallPrefab;
public GameObject TurretPrefab;
public static TurretBallManager instance;
public int turretSpawnTime=35;
public int LastTurretTime=0;
Vector2 v;
void Start () {
    instance = this;
    v = new Vector2(TurretPrefab.transform.position.x,TurretPrefab.transform.position.y);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Time.time > LastTurretTime + turretSpawnTime) {
        GameObject T = Instantiate(TurretPrefab,v,Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        //T.AddComponent<Turret>();
        v.x=T.transform.position.x+2;
    }
  }
}
```

Turret class :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Turret : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
double LastBallTime=0.0;
double LastTurretTime=0.0;
public decimal spawnballTime=1.5;
Vector2 v ;
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Time.time > LastBallTime + spawnballTime) {
        LastBallTime=Time.time;     
        Debug.Log (transform.position);
        GameObject B = Instantiate(TurretBallManager.instance.BallPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
        //B.AddComponent<Ball>();
    }

  }
}
```

Ball class :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}
void OnMouseDown() {
    Object.Destroy (gameObject);
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}


void OnBecameInvisible ()
{
    Debug.Log ("destroyed");
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
}
```

I have a turret wish fire a ball every 1 sec ,the ball is a prefab wish have the Ball class ( when the ball is out of bounds or is touched it should be destroyed ) what i'm trying to do is creating a another turret every `35 sec` wish also should fire a ball every 1 sec ..
what i am facing is the fallowing problem :

1. the turret is being created after `35 sec` but it's ball are not implementing the `ball script` and they are not being destroyed
2. An overflow is occurring due to the number of balls created and the whole project is freezing

[image: As soon as the game begin]

[image: When 35 seconds ends]

[image: you can see that millions of turrets are created at the same time as soon as 35 sec ends]

- Image 1 : as soon as the game begin
- Image 2 : When 35 seconds ends
- Image 3 : you can see that millions of turrets are created at the same time as soon as 35 sec ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these scripts out.

Attach the **TurretExampleManager** script to a GameObject (say Main Camera) and assign the "**turretPrefab** and the **ballPrefab** GameObjects then hit Play

**TurretExampleManager.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TurretExampleManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public static TurretExampleManager instance;

    //Maximum number of turrets that can spawn
    public int maxTurrets = 10;

    //The current number of turrets spawned
    private int currentTurrets = 0;

    //The time between turret spawns
    public float turretSpawnTime = 35;

    //Current spawn timer for turret
    public float thisTurretSpawnTime = 35;

    //Assign this prefab as the turret
    public GameObject turretPrefab;

    //Assign this prefab as the ball
    public GameObject ballPrefab;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        //Creating a static instance of the TurretExampleManager class.
        //This is used in the BallScript.cs class to access the Ball Prefab
        instance = this;

        //Assigning the decrementing time counter the same as the time between spawns
        thisTurretSpawnTime = turretSpawnTime;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        //Let's first check if we have the maximum number of turrets already (10 in this case)
        if(currentTurrets < maxTurrets) {

             //We have fewer than 10 turrets, so let's reduce the current time counter
             thisTurretSpawnTime -= Time.deltaTime;

            //The current time counter has hit 0, so we need to create a new turret
            if(thisTurretSpawnTime <= 0) {

                SpawnNewTurret();                       //Spawn a new turret
                thisTurretSpawnTime = turretSpawnTime;  //Reset the time
            }
        }
    }

    public void SpawnNewTurret () {
        //Increment the current number of turrets
        currentTurrets++;

        //Create a random position to spawn the new turret at
        Vector3 randomPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-10, 10), 0, Random.Range(-10, 10));

        //Instantiate a new turret
        GameObject thisTurret = Instantiate(turretPrefab, randomPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

        //Add the Turret Script
        thisTurret.AddComponent<TurretScript>();
    }
}
```

**TurretScript.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TurretScript : MonoBehaviour {

    //This variable controls the rate of ball spawn
    public float ballFireTime = 1;

    //Counter for time.
    public float thisBallFireTime = 1;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        thisBallFireTime = ballFireTime;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        //Reduce the time 
        thisBallFireTime -= Time.deltaTime;

        //If the time reaches 0, we need to spawn a new ball
        if(thisBallFireTime <= 0) {

            //Reset the ball spawn time
            thisBallFireTime = ballFireTime;

            //Instantiate a new ball
            GameObject thisBall = Instantiate(TurretExampleManager.instance.ballPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

            //Add the Ball Script to the newly spawned ball
            thisBall.AddComponent<BallScript>();
        }
    }
}
```

**BallScript.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BallScript : MonoBehaviour {

    private Vector3 randomDirection = Vector3.zero;

    void Start () {

        //Create a random direction for the ball to move in
        randomDirection = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1, 1), 0, Random.Range(-1, 1));
    }

    void OnMouseDown() {
        Debug.Log ("Destroyed because out of click");
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    void OnBecameInvisible () {
        Debug.Log ("Destroyed because out of bounds");
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    void Update () {
        //Move the ball in the random direction generated
        transform.Translate(randomDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: I added inline comments to all the scripts. If you need help understanding, let me know

Comment: I figure out the bug in my code , i really appreciate your code i find out many things to add to my script the problem was after this line : `if (Time.time > LastTurretTime + turretSpawnTime) {` i didn't update the `LastTurretTime` i forgot to add this line `LastTurretTime =Time.time;` ,everything work out fine now . thank you so much